# How to identify which viewholder.webview should be call the onpause() method

Tags: android, listview, webview, youtube

I have a listview where each item has webview inside it playing embeded youtube videos.
But the problem is whenever I press back button, the audio keeps playing in background.

I already tried webview.onpause() on activity's onpause method. But ita not working.

May be the call of viewholder.webview.onpause() in adapter class is not stopping the actual viweholder in which the video is being played .

How to identify which viewholder.webview should be made called onpause().

Please find the code below.

```
enter code here
```

public class VideoGallaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<VideoItem> mItemList;
private Activity mContext;
private ViewHolder holder;
private String part2;
private WebView currentWebview;
int position;

public VideoGallaryAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<VideoItem> itemList)
{
    mContext = context;
    mItemList = itemList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mItemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mItemList.get(position).hashCode();
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    WebView displayYoutubeVideo;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
    VideoItem item = mItemList.get(position);
    String video_url = item.getmVideoUrl();
    this.position = position;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView =  LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.video_item_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    String[] parts = video_url.split("v=");
    part2 = parts[1];
    part2 = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+part2+"?rel=0";

    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    return convertView;
}


public void stopwebView(){
   if(holder!=null && holder.displayYoutubeVideo!=null)
        holder.displayYoutubeVideo.onPause();
}

public void resumeWebView(){
    if(holder!=null && holder.displayYoutubeVideo!=null)
    holder.displayYoutubeVideo.onResume();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Putting the web view in list view is not a valid approach. You probably should think differently. Let's share your problem code.

Comment: I have added my code.
Please have a look guys

Comment: @BhavdipSagar I tried thinking of using youtube API approach for listview items at first, but the jar file would cost adding 100kb of size to my apk.

Can you suggest some other approach for this .? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There can sure possible using lots of ways but you must clear before start implement. Yes, Let's say you can use Youtube API and native android component, play the youtube content into the application.